# How can I use this snippet to do something different for each language detected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Someone referenced this snippet to me found from [How to getting browser current locale preference using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678230)

```
  var l_lang;
 if (navigator.userLanguage) // Explorer
  l_lang = navigator.userLanguage;
 else if (navigator.language) // FF
  l_lang = navigator.language;
 else
  l_lang = "en";
```

I am wondering how I can add on to it to do something for each language. How do I return the language and do something for each using this if then statement? This is what I was thinking.

```
    var l_lang;
 if (navigator.userLanguage) // Explorer
  l_lang = navigator.userLanguage;
 else if (navigator.language) // FF
  l_lang = navigator.language;
 else
  l_lang = "en"; 
  'do something
  l_lang = "fr"; 
  'do something
  l_lang = "ru"; 
  'do something
  l_lang = "de"; 
  'do something
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write an if-else block in javascript?

Comment: and what does this have to do with programming with Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a javascript switch statement ([documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp))

```
switch(l_lang)
{
case 'en':
  //execute code block 1
  break;
case 'fr':
  //execute code block 2
  break;
default:
  //code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
}
```