# Is there a way to parse a string in javascript into a number with respect to the locale

Tags: javascript, locale

I'm editing a web based program at the moment. It is used all over the globe. I'm adding a number based field. I want to be able to allow the end user to enter in the number the way they want in their local locale. I see that there is a function called Number.toLocaleString() that will give me what I need. However, I can't seem to find an inverse function.

Take the string "1,000" for example. If my user's locale is en-US, I want it to be interpreted  as 1000. If my user's locale is de-DE then it should be interpreted as 1. What is the standard way of doing this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has pretty much no locale support beyond just detecting what is set. For that, see the navigator object, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678230/how-to-getting-browser-current-locale-preference-using-javascript) other question.

If you want locale specific parsing, you'll need to use one of the many libraries out there.  Checkout [localplanet](http://www.localeplanet.com/). It has a formatter for integers and decimals.