# Get IE browser language in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway by which we can get the IE browser language

I tried navigator.lanuage , navigator.userLanguage etc...nothing works :( .

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for [Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4)

> The Accept-Language request-header field is similar to Accept, but
>   restricts the set of natural languages that are preferred as a
>   response to the request.

An example could be like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "http://abcd.com", 
    dataType: 'jsonp', 
    success: function(headers) {
        language = headers['Accept-Language'];
       //..........
    }
});
```

Also check [How to getting browser current locale preference using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678230/how-to-getting-browser-current-locale-preference-using-javascript)