# Chrome, javascript Date and toLocaleString()

Tags: javascript, date, google-chrome

Why doesn't Chrome specify AM or PM when displaying a date by using `date.toLocaleString()` ? The string I get is `Fri Jun 25 2010 11:21:09 GMT+1000`. While IE returns almost the same string but with `AM` after the time.

Is there any method on the `Date` object I can call to check whether it's `AM` or `PM` and, more importantly, check whether user's locale is using 12-hour cycles or 24-hours?

**Update.** Found this bug http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=135. It is very old, I was hoping there would be updates on it.

Comment: Bug report is continued in [Issue 180](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=180).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) returns a value between `0` and `23`, so you can easily determine whether it's before or after noon.

However, I don't know any method to get a kind of universal locale string. It's completely up to the browser:

> The contents of the String are
>   implementation-dependent, but are
>   intended to represent the Date in the
>   current time zone in a convenient,
>   human-readable form that corresponds
>   to the conventions of the host
>   environment’s current locale.
>   – [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), § 15.9.5.5

Instead, you can more or less [test the user's language setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference) and build a string yourself.

Comment: The language setting is not a reliable indicator of preferred date format. Far better to just use an unambiguous format. ;-)