# Chrome Extension /Javascript- detecting user language in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What I need to know is:

[image]

self explaining image :)

Is this language selection possible in the Chrome Browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript for detecting browser language preference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)

Comment: Why a bloated GIF instead of JPEG or at least PNG?

Comment: Are you trolling? I mean, don't tell me you just had to upload the whole desktop just to show that tiny part on lower right

Comment: the problem with "self explaining image" is that the link can be broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would the internalization API work for you?
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/i18n.html

If you want to get the systems language from Windows Language bar, you would need to use NPAPI http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html to get the language. You would need to create a plugin that fetches the windows settings for language and use that for your extension.

That might be a valid request for i18n, perhaps create an issue for that http://crbug.com/new

Comment: hmm not really..
because i need to know user's language
but thanks for your answers

Answer (score 3):

below code shows the user language

```
alert(window.navigator.language);//works both in Mozilla and chrome
alert(navigator.language);//works both in Mozilla and chrome
alert(navigator.userLanguage);// Works in IE
```

JSfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nirus/9FVTf/)

Answer (score 1):

If you need something different than the i18n API Mansour mentioned, use `navigator.language`.

Comment: but navigator.language gives me en
i need to get the current language the user writes on..
for example i got english and hebrew language as my "Region and Languages" preference in windows
so if i am currently using hebrew than i need to get "he" but if i currently writing in english than i should get "en"
it isnt related to the language i prefer in Google Chrome