# Get the current keyboard layout language in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows, keyboard-layout

I am using wshShell.SendKeys to input some text into web sites from an HTA, when my current keyboard layout is not English, the results of wshShell.SendKeys is unanticipated.

I want my function to check rather the language is English, otherwise send ALT+SHIFT to change it to English.. The hard part for me is to find a function that returns the current keyboard layout.

If anyone is familiar with a way doing it, I will be glad to know..

Thanks,
Rotem

Comment: Not sure if any of this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference

Comment: Hi, the examples in the link are returning the browser / system language and not the current keyboard layout language. But thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I made it with 'Shadow Wizard''s help..

This is the code, if anyone want to know (=

Thanks!

```
    var lastKeyPressed = 0;

function sendKey()
{
    var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.SendKeys( 'a' );
}

function getCurLayout()
{
    sendKey();
    setTimeout("lastKeyLang()",10);
}

function lastKeyLang()
{
    if( lastKeyPressed == 97 )
        alert( 'EN' );
    else
        alert( 'HE' );  
}

document.onkeypress = saveLastKey;  
function saveLastKey()
{
    lastKeyPressed = window.event.keyCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send "A" to textbox, read it back like this:

```
nValue = oTextbox.value.charCodeAt(0);
```

If `nValue` is 65 layout is English otherwise it's not and probably `ש` was sent instead.

Comment: Already tried, it didn't work. it returned 65 nither it was in English or not.. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Rotem didn't try it myself with SendKeys just with ordinary JS so figured it might work..

Comment: Ok, I'll try it now and let you know! Thanks!