# How to know the char on a specific keyboard position with JS

Tags: javascript, keyboard, midi, keyboard-layout

## Problem

I want to know what letters correspond to the different row of keys in the user's keyboard, using JS. An array representation of what I want would be something like this:

```js
// ANSI QWERTY layout for English - USA
const usaKeyboardLayout = [
  ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '[', ']', '\\'], // literal '\' escaped
  ['a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ';', "'"],
  ['z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', ',', '.', '/']
]

// ISO QWERTY layout for Spanish - Spain
const spanishKeyboardLayout = [
  ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '`', '+'],
  ['a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'ñ', '´', 'ç'],
  ['<', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', ',', '.', '-']
]
```

From [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892238/detect-keyboard-layout-with-javascript) and the [keyboard layout wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Mechanical_layouts) it doesn't look like there's a standard that I could map to the locale or anything like that. I mean, even my keyboard configuration has around a hundred groups, each of them with 1 or more layout, with one of the groups called "others". Let alone keyboards for non-latin alphabets.

I don't think there's a standard way to find out this information, but I was wondering if there's something clever I could do to solve this problem.

I've already tried triggering synthetic events with a `keyCode` to try and get the `key` back, but it came empty.

## Context

My end goal is to implement some kind of instrument controller with the keyboard. Programs that have MIDI input capabilities (e.g. ableton) allow the user to play a piano-like layout with the keyboard. With a QWERTY layout, for example, this is the equivalence between keyboard keys and piano keys:

- <kbd>`A`</kbd>: C / Do
- <kbd>`W`</kbd>: C# / Do#
- <kbd>`S`</kbd>: D / Re
- <kbd>`E`</kbd>: D# / Re#
- <kbd>`D`</kbd>: E / Mi
- <kbd>`F`</kbd>: F / Fa

  ...And so on

I'd like to show the keyboard keys that the user has to press to play different instrument keys, but so far I can only hardcode them

Comment: You could let the user make inputs for every row, but this would be probably not the best user-experience. By the way think of mobile devices or parted keyboards.

Comment: Good points. For touch devices we though of just using touch inputs, so keyboards should not be needed. For parted keyboards I guess the user would have to apply extra imagination to think they're playing an instrument with continuous keys. I thought about the user having to press all the keys, but it doesn't feel right from the UX perspective, as you mention. I was hoping there was a way to do something like that with JS instead of requesting user's actions

Comment: If it helps, here are standard windows keyboard layouts http://kbdlayout.info/ you can download each layout as xml.