# Detect keyboard layout with Javascript, in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Is there a way to detect a client's keyboard layout in Firefox?

I know the answer is yes with Chrome (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/keyboard):

```
navigator.keyboard.getLayoutMap().then(function(k) { console.log(k.get('KeyQ')); } // A or Q gives a hint about the layout
```

Is there another way for other browsers (Firefox, Safari, etc.) ?

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to achieve by detecting a keyboard's layout?

Comment: You could ask them to press the first 5 keys of the first 2 rows in order and check for matches.

Comment: Related, but the answers there don't support Firefox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892238/detect-keyboard-layout-with-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to detect the keyboard layout through Javascript in Firefox.

---

The feature is currently experimental in Chromium based browsers. For Firefox you can track the progress here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1469017

As of today the last update on the bug was 2020-06-05. One of the last substantial posts in that thread said:

> [...] exposing this information is really strong fingerpintting source. Finally, Apple has already refused. So, I think that we do not need to this API.

---

You can follow Mozilla's official position on this API here: https://mozilla.github.io/standards-positions/#keyboard-map

Currently it's classified as "harmful", and states:

> We're concerned that this exposes keyboard layouts, which seem likely to be a significant source of fingerprinting data, in a way that does not require any user interaction.

---

I do not expect this capability will be supported on Firefox in the foreseeable future.