# Check what symbol a given modifier and keycode combination would produce in a browser?

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I would like to implement hotkeys in a web application using the [`.code` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) of the received keyboard events, as those seem to be the correct way to produce layout-independent bindings. The only issue is that while I'm completely fine with ignoring the produced symbols under the hood, I would still like to show the user the keyboard hints that they need to press adjusted to their own layouts.

For examply I would like to keep the shortcut for Undo to be the the left shift and the key right next to it (*"KeyZ"*, keycode `0x002C`), but on for example the Hungarian layout (see below), that key produces the symbol `Y`, so I would like to show the user the following hint: *"Undo (Ctrl + Y)"*.

[image: hungarian-keyboard-layout]

Is that achievable in some way? I tried searching for a browser API, that would map modifiers and keycodes to symbols on the currently active layout, but couldn't find any, and I couldn't come up with any possible workaround either.

Answer (score 0):

After searching around again and again for several days trying to figure something out (experimenting with synthetic keyboard events and such...) I have finally came across an attempt towards a possible solution:
https://wicg.github.io/keyboard-map/#keyboardlayoutmap-interface

The provided example on MDN is exactly the same use case I was looking for:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardLayoutMap#examples

Sadly it is [not currently available in Firefox](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_keyboardlayoutmap), and the resources that this answer points to make it seem like there's a pretty low chance of it getting implemented anytime soon:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69378454/1831096