Determining Current Keyboard Language Settings for External Input in Tizen TV Web Application
I'm working on developing an input field for my Tizen TV web application and have observed that when using an external keyboard, the text entered in the Tizen browser or Search apps reflects the language settings configured in the Input Device Manager -> Keyboard Settings. However, I'm not sure how to identify the current settings. How can I check which keyboard language is currently active?
I attempted to use
const keyboardLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

but it didn't return the language setting of the external keyboard. The same issue occurred when I tried using the
tizen.systeminfo.getPropertyValue("LOCALE",{}) API


You may find this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892238/detect-keyboard-layout-with-javascript useful, however it doesn't directly refer to keyboard settings.
