# Identify keyboard language before keypress in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was able to find code for [getting current keyboard language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402849/get-the-current-keyboard-layout-language-in-javascript)
on-key-press, but I want to get this data on-click.
Meaning, when the user click on screen -> alert('EN/FR/SP').

Maybe it's an OS issue and not related to browser, but is
there a way to create a code like this (Javascript or other)?

Comment: _Why_ do you need the keyboard language?

Answer (score 0):

Does the following not work?

```
$('body').on('click', function(){
    alert(navigator.language);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but these codes give me the browser's lang, while I want the OS keyboard lang (the language you're currently typing in the browser).

Comment: Oh OK, can I ask why on earth you would need that information?

Comment: Found this, trying to understand if it can help (Mac): https://github.com/Lutzifer/keyboardSwitcher

Comment: Hey Adam, I want to get an app for school's project able to detect your lang at any time, little hard to explain the whole process, but it has to know keyboard language.

Comment: Please see Jukka K. Korpela answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892238/detect-keyboard-layout-with-javascript. Think that should answer your question once and for all

Comment: I think it does, I'll have to use  a different approach - maybe Java or C++. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

I think the best you can do is get the browser's language, but of course that's not necessarily the same thing:

```js
var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
document.write(lang);
```