# How can I get and parse Accept Header to get language at JavaScript?

Tags: regex, internationalization, header

How can I get and parse Accept Header to get language as two character => en, tr, ar, fr, etc. at JavaScript?

**EDIT:** When I use

> navigator.language

or something like that it gives me a language. However I am using a plug-in at Firefox, Quick Locale, it changes the local. When I change it from English to Arabic, still navigator.language says that I am using English. However when I connect to www.google.com, after I changed locale with Quick Locale, Google's homepage opens at Arabic language. I want to detect the user's language as like that. I will load the language properties of my HTML file after I detected the language as like Google.

**EDIT2:**
There is a code for my purpose here:
[accept header script](https://github.com/dansingerman/jQuery-Browser-Language/blob/master/jquery.browserLanguage.js)

However it makes a call to that URL: http://ajaxhttpheaders.appspot.com

How can I get the source code at that URL?

**EDIT3:**
Can I write something similar to that code at my server side (to communicate my HTML side via REST - this is last solution for me) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference

Comment: @fifteen3, I have edited my code to be more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript). But you can try to [detect browser language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference).

Edit: If you would like to change site content depending on accept header (like google) then you have to do it on server side.