# How to get the browser language using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript for detecting browser language preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)

I want to detect the language of the browser that is entering my site, if it's En or Fr. So I can redirect to the En page or the other page.

Also, can I detect mobile language?

Comment: Probably better off doing this with HTTP headers like `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`

Comment: Take a look at this similar question/answer.

[StackOverflow - JavaScript for detecting browser language preference][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference

Answer (score 482, accepted):

Try this script to get your browser language

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
alert ("The language is: " + userLang);
</script>
```

Comment: equivalent and more JS-typical: `navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage`

Comment: My testing suggests that while this works in IE and Firefox, it does not work in Chrome.  Chrome's navigator.language is always the language configuration of the installation of windows, rather than the language configuration of the browser.

Comment: +1 @kybernetikos, This is something to be addressed since most of the people use Chrome.

Comment: Running Mac OS X, I tried Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, all returned the language of my box, did not matter what language the page is.

Comment: will not work in IE11

Comment: @ses @cevaris @kybernetikos browser updates since 2011 mean that adding `|| navigator.languages` should increase compatbility especially with newer versions of browsers.

Comment: If you want to use a library, you can also use `acceptedlanguages.js` which is entirely javascript and browser compatible covering all the cases: https://github.com/leighmcculloch/acceptedlanguages.js

Comment: It doesn't work for me on IE 11 and Microsoft Edge (64bit, Windows 10 - it seems to be configured by Control Panel settings on this system so it may be the issue)

Comment: Not working with IE always giving en-US as the language

Comment: @SathOkh + 1 on this. navigator.language exists in IE but never gets updated when changing the browser language. navigator.languages works fine in Chrome/FF

Comment: Update: There is now (2020) an experimental feature supported by all modern browsers that returns an array of language preference: navigator.languages //["en-US", "zh-CN", "ja-JP"] This should work on at least 95% of browsers in 2020.

Comment: var userLang = (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage).slice(0,2)

Answer (score 55):

The "JavaScript" way:

```
var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; //no ?s necessary
```

Really you should be doing language detection on the server, but if it's absolutely necessary to know/use via JavaScript, it can be gotten.

Comment: why should it be done on the server? seems like a redundant comment.

Comment: @Paul, language detection should be done on the server so that the content is served in the appropriate language. To do otherwise would be wasteful of the user's bandwidth.

Comment: @zzzzBov I've been working on a Ember.js app with full language support, where I use the navigator.language as part of my API calls, so no user bandwidth is wasted. But I guess your right. It's an edge case.

Comment: This answer is pretty old but today SPA works most of the time on static server-less env, so doing this with Javascript is more than legit.

Comment: @SeLeCtRa, I appreciate the enthusiasm behind your edit, but I think you'd be better off writing your own answer than trying to revive this one.