# Display links in specific country only

Tags: javascript, blogger

I want to show some links only if the user from india,in my blogger blog. But only with js, without php or any other language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the browser language using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199760/how-to-get-the-browser-language-using-javascript)

Comment: Could be a duplicate of [How to get visitor's location (i.e. country) using javascript geolocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489460/how-to-get-visitors-location-i-e-country-using-javascript-geolocation).

Answer (score -1):

You could read Navigator for localization and change the attribute of the html element.

[Using language | NavigatorLanguage.language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language)

Using location | Navigator.geolocation (can't post 2 links)
"developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation"

```
const changeLink = document.querySelector(".theLinkThatChanges"); 

if (window.navigator.language == 'EN') {
  changeLink.setAttribute("src", "https://www.englishlink.here");
}
```

Note: I added my own answer after clicking through 4 of those "duplicates" without clear and sourced top answers.