# How to print/echo visitor browser language through javascript

Tags: javascript, php

From the following JavaScript:

```
<script>
var language = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
</script>
```

...is then possible to echo text related visitor's browser language?

For example: `You are watching MyMovieTitle [<?php echo navigator.language ?>]`

The javascript should provide me the full language word.
Example: 'English'; 'German'; 'French' and so on...

Comment: No. PHP gets parsed on the server, way before it even reaches the users browser (where the javascript is executed) and you can't echo Javascript variables with PHP.

Comment: You can create an array after detecting user language and print message according to array value `alert ("The language is: " + language);`

Comment: If you really need the language in PHP, you can check if the browser sends the language as a header. Here's ha post about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770513/detect-browser-language-in-php

Comment: Can't you just output `language` in the browser via JS? Whys the PHP needed?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - In theory you're partially correct. But, the server is receiving a request from the browser, so, it can receive locale information along with that.

Comment: @Rtra language.indexOf('fr') = 'Français'; else if language.indexOf('de') = 'Deutsch' and so on... Would be real long. That's why I want the system to detect and print itself. So that in case of Czech Republic; Sweden, Russia, and so on, it will do it alone, without me pre-inserting the whole country list and words...

Comment: @ChicöLatinö - Do check my reply. Hope that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the browser language using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199760/how-to-get-the-browser-language-using-javascript)

Comment: Nope it isn't. I'm not asking how to get browser language. But how to print entire language word.

Comment: @UmashankarDas - Wasn't that exactly what I said in my second post? My first post was about using js-variables in PHP, which you can't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just print the javascript variable

```
navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
```

But, since, you want,the PHP version use this variable.

```
$locale = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
echo $locale;
$language = locale_get_display_language($locale);
echo $language; // Non-Ugly version :) . Got anglais for en-US
```

Please check above and see.

Comment: Ugly Results. Wow. Anyhow, check the modified answer. FYI Stackoverflow is not built to give you tailormade data. It will give you the path to go forward.  Incidentally, the result above will be fr-FR since, q is 0.8 which sounds highest. Surely you can learn to parse that.

Comment: Now reports: "Call to undefined function locale_accept_from_http() ..."

Comment: which version of php are you using ?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: You need to read some PHP. You can get php version by doing this. 
echo phpinfo(); If you version is < 5.3.x then you need to parse the previous output from the accept header // The Ugly version :)

Comment: PHP Version 5.4.45

Comment: If useful, I'm using wordpress. And I can tell you if I just try to add <?php $locale = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
$language = locale_get_display_language($locale);?> in my header.php file, the whole site cant be open, due to a syntax error...

Comment: @ChicöLatinö - Make sure that you have installed the PHP extension `php5-intl`, which is required for the above functions.

Comment: Is this stuff based on my website server side, or involves my browser(s) in use? I ask coz in first case it would be a solution, making visitors see what I plan to; viceversa in second case I would be able to display correct word, but all visitors without php5-intl installed wouldnt.

Comment: Now worked. Thanks a lot both. Especially Magnus Eriksson who gave me the ultimate input.