# How to get browser language in portlet

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I have to check the browser language based on the language i am performing my business logic.

My portlet `doProcessAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)` accepts request and response.
I checked `actionRequest.getLocale()` which return every time `en_IN` as a language even though my browser language selected as `hi_IN`(which is hindi).

Any input from any one is highly appreciated.

Comment: As you tag Liferay: What's the language that the rest of Liferay's UI is displayed in? en or hi?

Answer (score 0):

Browser language is not linked with liferay portal languages.
Liferay will return you the language which user has set in his preferences.
Control panel -> user settings -> Display Settings

[User Profile/Language settings in Liferay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVXH0.png)

To get browser language go with this article
[get browser language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199760/how-to-get-the-browser-language-using-javascript)