# How to get browser IP address and the visitors country, who visited my site, without doing any API call

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

How to get browser IP address and the visitors country, who visited my site, without doing any API call. suppose that my site is www.xyz.com. and anyone is putting my site url in browser address bar. on hiting my url, i should get browser IP address and the visitors country.

Comment: Is it a duplicate if the OP explicitly excludes the first answer on the duplicate question, but didn't bother to scroll down to the second answer?:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32841164/328193  That's for IP address at least.  "Country" doesn't seem as likely to be findable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get client's IP address using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. The browser is not aware of the public ip address he uses.

To get the country you can look at the language ([How to get the browser language using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199760/how-to-get-the-browser-language-using-javascript)) and try to get the users geolocation  (https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_geolocation.asp)

Comment: Of course it is not an accurate information, but it can be hint. I just tried to show up the possibilities.