# Custom Angular pipe to display date according to locale of the application

Tags: angular, date, angular-pipe

I have three date formats displayed below :-

```
en-GB   –             DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss
en-US   –             MM/DD/ YYYY hh:mm:ss
zh-cn || zh –         YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss
```

I have to develop an angular pipe which actually detects the locale / Browser language or language from the localstorage which i stored it should format the date according to the language of the application

i.e

```
if language is en-GB then it should format the date in --> DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss
or 
if language is en-US then it should format the date in -->  MM/DD/ YYYY hh:mm:ss
or
if language is zh-cn || zh then it should format the date in -->  YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss
```

Please any code referral or any link it would be an ultimate help from you people.

thank's

Answer (score 0):

according to your requirement you can use DatePipe service which you can import from @angular/common lib

here is the example

```
import { DatePipe } from "@angular/common";
```

in your component just add into your @Component decoretor

```
 providers: [DatePipe]
```

and

```
gb = new Date();
  zh = new Date();
  us = new Date();

constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
    this.gb = this.datePipe.transform(this.gb, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    this.us = this.datePipe.transform(this.us, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    this.zh = this.datePipe.transform(this.zh, "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
 }
```

here you should write constructor code according to your localstorage value what you are getting.
and I hope you are getting language from somewhere(localstorage) or you have stored it.
if you are not getting language of browser than you can get it click on below link it will help you to get browser language

[How to get the browser language using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199760/how-to-get-the-browser-language-using-javascript)

after it below link also will help you
[Angular - Use pipes in services and components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-use-pipes-in-services-and-components)

hope this would help you, let me know if you need any help regarding it.

thanks,
Kushal