# Set language in Mapbox Static Image

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-static-maps

I am using the Mapbox Static Image API to show users an image of a slice of a map relating to the page they are viewing. Our users are from many countries and expect properly localized country, city names etc.

**Question**
Is it possible to set the language of all labels in a Mapbox Static Image somehow?

I think I can achieve this by creating a Mapbox Studio Style for each language we want to support, but we have quite a lot of customization in our custom style so I would rather avoid having to manually maintain a version for all supported languages.

I have tried using the playground https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/static/ and also read through the documentation, without finding anything reminiscent of setting the locale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your only option is to create multiple styles for each language you want to support.
You probably use a call like this to get your map:

```
/styles/v1/{username}/{style_id}/static/{overlay}/{lon},{lat},{zoom},{bearing},{pitch}|{auto}/{width}x{height}{@2x}
```

Use javascript to find your users browser preferred language: [How to get the browser language using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199760/how-to-get-the-browser-language-using-javascript)

and change your {style_id} to the requested language.

Another option that comes to mind is to try to use multiple layers.
All the background data and (complex) style in one layer, and make a separate layer with your labels. This way you only need to have different styles for your labels and the maintenance will be less of a hassle.

Comment: So if I understand your second method correctly, I should remove the country, county and settlement labels from my Studio style and use the AddLayer option for the Static Image API to add them with the correct language? I guess that could work as a better and more scalable solution