# Detect Chrome Browser Language when running Vaadin Integration Test Class

Tags: java, selenium, localization, vaadin, test-bench

I am using Vaadin Testbench to implement test imulations. I have to check whether the Chrome Browsers language is English or German and based on that I have to set values either in English or German to simulate.

How to detect Chrome browser language when running the Integration test class? Based on the language detected I will set the language in the Chrome Driver parameters.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199760/how-to-get-the-browser-language-using-javascript

Comment: This is with respect to Vaadin Testbench in Java language. This question is not a duplicate.  Vaadin Testbench uses SElenium in Java.

Comment: The page is not answering my question.

Comment: You can use js even in Java, see https://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html

Answer (score 0):

Using Vaadin `TestBench`, you can retrieve the language via a JavaScript call like so

```
String language = (String) executeScript(
                "let language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;"
                + "return language");
```

Note also that rather than retrieving the language, it might be useful to set it explicitly yourself like so

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--lang=es");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```