# Find the language of the user computer (web)

Tags: javascript, html, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript for detecting browser language preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)

Is it possible to find from a web app the language of the user computer/browser? I'm using html5 and js. I'm not searching for ipdatabases solutions, you may be able to find the country language but not the computer.

Comment: Would [Localization - JavaScript for detecting browser language preference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference) be of use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you're looking for [window.navigator.language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/window.navigator.language)

Comment: How simple, thank you! I've must been searching the wrong words, i couldn't find an answer on google.

Answer (score 2):

To do this from the server side, you can lookout for the ["Accept-Language" header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4). This gives the user's preference of languages as set in the browser.

Other JS versions are not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    var userLang = (navigator.language) ?     
    navigator.language : navigator.userLanguage;   alert ("The language is: " + 
        userLang);  
</script>
```

Comment: From  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534713%28VS.85%29.aspx .language is going to return OS preference and not IE's

Comment: Yes, i prefer the computer language, the browser was a secondary choice. Thank you.