# Hot to get user’s regional settings for currency in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimal, currency-formatting, regional-settings

I’m trying to format some numbers with jQuery. I would like to get the user’s regional settings for currency and number, in order to implement the correct format (obtain the decimal separator).

Is it possible to retrieve these parameters with jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format numbers and dates based on user locale settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205873/how-to-format-numbers-and-dates-based-on-user-locale-settings)

Comment: `2343.4 .toLocaleString() ` will show you the decimal in most browsers, and thousands in at least chrome...

Answer (score 6):

Use [**`Number.toLocaleString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) with `style:'currency'`:

```js
(73.57).toLocaleString('de-DE',{style:'currency',currency:'EUR'}); // German: 73,57 €
(73.57).toLocaleString('en-US',{style:'currency',currency:'EUR'}); // American: €73.57
```

Note that:

- This does not *get* regional settings, but *provides* output in regional settings.
- If you want your locale to be determined dynamically, use [`navigator.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language).
- There are many other means aside from this native approach; for starters, take a look at [accounting.js](https://github.com/openexchangerates/accounting.js) or Stack Overflow answers [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript).

---

<sup>*As [Daniel Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5875331/daniel-jackson) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561412/hot-to-get-user-s-regional-settings-for-currency-in-javascript-or-jquery#comment105663497_33561563):*</sup>

Using [**`Intl.NumberFormat.format()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/format), you can achieve identical results, with the [`NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) and the general [`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) objects offering versatile options and methods with a main focus on language sensitivity.

```js
new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE',{style:'currency',currency:'EUR'}).format(73.57); // DE: 73,57 €
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US',{style:'currency',currency:'EUR'}).format(73.57); // US: €73.57
```

Comment: holy cow, when did this sneak into JS? even has IE11 support. awesome, just awesome.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was how to retrieve the currency settings, not how to format a currency.

Comment: @raarts: Formatting was the actual goal (“format some numbers”), and since there is no (native) way to output applicable parameters, that was the first note I gave. Furthermore, if you need those “regional parameters” at all costs, you can always extract them: `let decimalSeparator = (1.23).toLocaleString(navigator.language,{style:'currency',currency:'EUR'}).match(/1(.)23/)[1];`. However, please note that I already put that into perspective, just read “Note that”.

Comment: I'm doing, `"$250".toLocaleLowerCase('en-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' })` but no matter what I try to enter the output is always $250. I've also tried `toLocaleString()` and I'm met with the same result.

Comment: However I did get this to work `var formatter =  new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'EUR',
});

console.log(formatter.format('2500'));`

Comment: The NumberFormat options require that, if `style:currency` then `currency:<something>`.  
Now, haw to find the current user's <something>?  
It has to be an ISO 4217 currency code.  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#Syntax

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin for it - https://github.com/dansingerman/jQuery-Browser-Language

See this SO answer for more info [JavaScript for detecting browser language preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)