# jQuery format currency from USD to browser's locale currency?

Tags: jquery

I am displaying a price for a product in USD dollars as default, this never changes so I know that it is always in USD.

I need to convert that price including the currency symbol to the user's browsers locale, this means that if that user lives in Israel, and then moves with his computer to USA, the price will still display in Israeli New Shekel.

Is there a way to do such thing that does not base the currency off the user's country by IP?

Comment: JS won't provide you with the locale currency symbol or the "USD to locale currency" conversion rates. That you'd would to arrange yourself or use some 3rd party. The formatting of price and currency can be done though. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33561563/2652134

Answer (score 0):

> You can use geoplugin library from here  [geoplugin.com](http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/javascript)

and do something like following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currencyCode = geoplugin_currencyCode();
});
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer. Does that plugin get the information by the location off the IP?

Comment: It seems to be using the IP. I suggest you read the plugin link.