# Automatic Language Selection without click on flag

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript for detecting browser language preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)

Hello i have a website in english and i want when someone comes in my website to automatically load russian language without showing language table or click on flags to do that,i think javascript does that.

thank you

Comment: You choose the default language in your browser, so it's always there.

Comment: just select russian language in `onload` event using js

Comment: If you automatically want to load the russion version, why don't you serve it at first?