# window.location.replace wtih Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, globalization

I try setup a JS function to auto load a index page in a different language, regardig the setting device o my reader.

I try with this...but don't work :

```
<script src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            function checkLanguage() {
                if (navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage()='en_EN')

                {
                window.location.replace("index_en.html");
            }

            else if (navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage()='fr_FR')
            {
                window.location.replace("index_fr.html");
            }
            else
            {
                window.location.replace("index_other.html");
            }

        }
</script>
```

Is this method can be use, or do I have to consider other option to deal with my multilanguage app ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the callback of getPreferredLanguage:

```
var handleDeviceReady = function (event)
{
    navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
        function (language)
            {
                console.log("language: " + language.value + '\n');
                redirectToLocaleSpecificLogin(language.value);
            },
        function ()
            {
                console.log("Error getting language\n");
                redirectToLocaleSpecificLogin("en");
            }
    );
};

document.addEventListener("deviceready", handleDeviceReady, false);
```

Then inside of your callback (redirectToLocaleSpecificLogin in this case), you can do your redirects.

Answer (score 0):

most of the browsers use **language** property, IE uses **userLanguage**

`var lang = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;`

this should work in IE, SAFARI, CHROME and FF

**Edit:**

[JavaScript for detecting browser language preference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1043339/1618713) this link has more detailed discussion on this topic

Comment: Thanks, in my case, It will be only use on iPad, that's the reason that I need to use navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage wich is describe in PhoneGap API [link]http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#globalization.getPreferredLanguage[link]