# Highcharts graph in multiple languages?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, multilingual

I need to display quite a number of graphs in multiple languages. Now, what changes, are evidently the categories names, titles, units, etc. I guess that this is not a Highcharts issue, but a Javascript thing. I probably should create a multi-dimensional array with "fr", "en", .... "title", "units", ... "Emissions de CO2", "CO2 Emissions", .... And then include the languages parameter in the URL. Right?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options here.

1. Do as you suggested. Write javascript code which has all the language strings encoded, and use a URL prameter to select the correct language to display.
2. Do this server side. Use the URL parameter to produce the correct chart language on the server

Option 2 means that you return less code to the browser. It also has the option of looking at request headers to try to work out what language to use if none is supplied using the 'Accept-Language' header. More info on this here: [JavaScript for detecting browser language preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)