# How to change a choice selection with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a choice:

```
<select id="selectlang">
  <option value="en" selected>English</option>
  <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
</select>
```

Now, I would like to set the default value by inspecting the browser's language.

```
var lang = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
```

How can I modify the selection of a choice with jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("#selectlang").val(lang.split('-')[0]);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nkVmV/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var lang = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;

if(lang === 'en-US')
    $('#selectlang').val('en');
```

Also of note, IE (of course) [doesn't support this property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.language#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: The more I think about this one, the worse it gets. I'd avoid using this property **completely**, unless you have a really specific use case and know exactly which browser your users will be in. Last resort, this has been answered [very thoroughly here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference).

Comment: The `val()` function is quite solid. None existing values like `val("xx")` simply set the first option. Spending time on the if statements seems needless.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the select value with jQuery like this:

```
$("#selectlang").val(lang);
```

but most likely you will need to validate the value of `var lang = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;`

Answer (score 1):

You can select the value of a select box using [jQuery's val() function](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$("#selectlang").val("en");
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code will work for you, but you have to change the value of the options kile
en => en-US because `var lang = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;` will return the language code in the `en-US` format

```
$("#selectlang").val(lang );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('option:selected').attr('selected', false);
$('option[value="' + lang + '"]').attr('selected', true)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nkVmV/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues to solve:

1. You need to be able to parse the multiple possible values that `window.navigator.language` can return.
2. You need to alter the `select` option accordingly.

**Parsing the language string**

The first issue requires a (very slightly) more complex solution than testing if `lang == "en"`.

English can be denoted by `en`, but it can also be `en-us` (American English), `en-gb` (Great Britain), etc.  Similarly German can be `de`, `de-ch` (Switzerland), `de-at` (Austria), etc.  [Here's a helpful list of potential values](http://4umi.com/web/html/languagecodes.php).

So it's not going to work if you just test the raw value of `lang`.  The best solution seems to be to test only the first two characters of `lang`, using `lang.substr(0, 2)`.

**Adjusting the selected option of `#selectlang`**

Once you have the language string correctly parsed, you can change the selected `option` using `val()`.

**Put the two together**

```
var lang = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;

$("#selectlang").val(lang.substr(0, 2));
```