# Browser Language using javascripts

Tags: javascript, browser

I have a requirement where I need to check for the language configured on a browser.
I use

```
var userLang = (navigator.language) ? navigator.language : navigator.userLanguage;
```

to check for the browser language.

This works fine on Firefox and chrome etc.

The problem arises on Internet explorer.
When I debugged the javascript [using alert() :-)] the language was shown as en-EN eventhough i configured the browser with ge-GE.

Can anyone provide a solution for this.

Comment: The problem is `window.navigator.userLanguage` is IE only and it's the language set in Windows Control Panel - Regional Options and NOT browser language [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4079798/1092711).

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
    alert(language); //works for IE,CHROME,FF,SAFARI.
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)

Comment: Hi Guys

Thanks for all the response. However, I would like to point out that that the userLanguage, language etc returns the Operating language and not the browser language. So even if I change the language at IE to lets say French, the property still returns en-EN as the OS is in english....

Please note, this happens only on IE. Chrome and Firefox returns french code.

Comment: did u refer the link in my post?

Comment: for IE11 does not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `navigator.userLanguage` for IE and `navigator.language` for others

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4079798/406659