# Is there a way to detect right to left layouts dynamically using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization

I know I can look into the `navigator` object for the language using JavaScript. Is there a similar way to detect whether that language is a right to left language automatically, without having to have any configuration?

**Edit** I can't rely on the `dir` attribute, since that is what I'm attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You could look for the html attribute that specifies this, e.g.

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
```

In JavaScript you can get this property with:

```
var dir = document.documentElement.getAttribute('dir');
```

Of course this relies on the site proving the information.

***Update to answer following update to question:***

You can pull the text direction for each language from [Unicode's CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/cldr-features#TOC-Language-and-script-information)

Using `navigator.language` is apparently [not reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference). I'd render the HTML page on the back end after detecting preferred languages via the HTTP [Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) header. It'll probably be easier to maintain your database of text directions on the server side too.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I also need not to be dependent on that - i need to actually set that client side.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you wrote "without any configuration" but you can create a dictionary of `RTL` languages, check the browser language and set accordingly the `dir` parameter.

The dictionary will not change in the near future, you can barely consider it as a constant like `π`  and not a configuration