# How to detect user's language

Tags: javascript, html

I'm going to detect user's keyboard language by javascript. I got a input (type of text) which should be filled with Persian characters. So, I need to alarm users change their keyboard language if their language is not Persian.

What I have found is this:

```
window.navigator.language;
```

which detects browser's language which is always En-us.

How could I solve that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try like this:-

```
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
alert(language);
```

**navigator.userLanguage** works for IE

**window.navigator.language** works for firefox/opera/safari

Also check out this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)

Comment: It doesn't return keyboard language. It shows browser's language which is always `en-US`

Comment: @Super Hornet,Indeed.

Comment: Why is this answer accepted?