# How to detect user's type language on javascript?

Tags: javascript, detect

I want to detect user's type language on javascript. Is there any way to detect language?

I mean: [image]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557494/how-to-detect-users-language, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892238/detect-keyboard-layout-with-javascript

Comment: What is a "type language"?

Comment: Input type language, please see the screenshot

Comment: browser language ? os system language? input method language?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the browser language over [navigator api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator)