# Chrome browser - navigator.language doesn't return country code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, navigator

Since last few months
I got the problem to detect countryCode from window.navigator.language. My current language on chrome is French(Switzerland)

Currently it return only the language:

```
window.navigator.language: fr
```

It was return language-contryCode:

```
window.navigator.languge: fr-ch
```

I did a lot of try but currently I cannot detect it from chrome browser.
Do you have any idea to solve this problem ?
updated: This is my current setting:
[image]
And here is the result from chrome:
[image]
Hope I will get some help. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving browser language in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33204177/retrieving-browser-language-in-chrome)

Comment: Not really, since a few months ago, chrome changed their way to get navigator.language, I guess. I will update a picture of my setting language

Comment: This works fine for me, when I try a language like `en-US` - but not for `fr-CH`.

Comment: Yes. seems with english - it return that result but not with others

Comment: What are you planning to do with that information anyway? The language the browser is displayed in should usually be of way less importance to you, than the actual language preferences for _content_ the user specified.

Comment: Thanks for your answering and questions. Actually we having some application works in Switzerland which country speak difference languages, and the application must adapt that on specific locale.
Each locale they have difference day format and number seperator. That's what I need to reach.

Comment: Hm, maybe the `toLocale…` methods of Number and Date objects could be more helpful in that regard …?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug, and it has been reported to chromium

[navigator.language result differs between english and other languages](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=802006&can=2&q=regional&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Comment: In order to distinguish English and German I currently use a work around: (1.1).toLocaleString().substring(1,2) yields the decimal separator "," for German language setting.

Comment: Excellent workaround, it will also work to distinguish fr-fr using , (comma) and fr-ch using . (dot)