# Convert client date / time string to JSON date / time string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, django, datetime

I am trying to convert a client date / time string on a form into a JSON date / time string using JavaScript and moment (for a Django REST API back end).  Here is what I have so far:

```
document.getElementById("dt_tm").value = 
moment(document.getElementById("inp-st").value, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").toJSON();
```

Two problems with this:

1. The date format cannot be hard coded as the client may have a different date format,
2. moment adjusts the date / time  and I don't need it to do that because the back end performs that function (using Django time zones).

So for example:

```
moment("14/05/2016 18:00", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").toJSON() =
"2016-05-14T17:00:00.000Z"
```

When what I need is:

```
"2016-05-14T18:00"
```

(In this example my time zone is currently GMT+1.)

Comment: `JSON.stringify(new Date())` is `"2016-05-10T14:27:19.698Z"` if thats what your after

Comment: JSON.stringify appears to do the same thing as toJSON.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be hardcoded"? Wouldn't the format have to be hardcoded since it has to be sent as string?

Comment: I meant that the "DD/MM/YYYY" needs to change to "MM/DD/YYYY" on the client when in the US.

Comment: JSON date string should contain the zone info, otherwise it would be erroneous to convert it to Date object

Comment: @MaxZoom Right, so 4castle's answer needs a "Z" on the end of the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like [`toJSON`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-json/) to return the date in a different format, redefine `moment.fn.toJSON` to that it returns with your custom format instead of the default ISO8601 date format. This is outlined in the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-json/).

```
moment.fn.toJSON = function() { 
    return this.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mmZ"); 
};
```

Comment: That solves my main problem.  Although I still have the problem of switching to US date format on the client, I gave you the tick anyway.

Comment: I think there should be a "Z" on the end of the format!

Comment: Ok, I changed it. I don't know what that does exactly. Regarding the US date format, you can just use an if statement for "if the user is from the US, use the other format"

Comment: You are probably interested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25725882/5743988) if you want locale detection.

Comment: The "Z" ensures the time zone information is preserved.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. So for example, the output would be like `"2016-05-14T17:00+1:00"`?