# Parse a date based on user's locale

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to parse, validate and re-format dates in an HTML form using moment.js. Because the website is being used internationally I want to reformat the dates in D MMM YYYY format (eg: 1 Apr 2018) to minimise any confusion once they've been entered.

The textboxes in my code are defined as follows:

```
<input type="text" class="txt-date" name="foo" />
```

And the JavaScript I've written to do the validation/re-formatting is as follows:

```
$(function () {

    console.log("initial locale: " + moment.locale());
    console.log("initial date format:= " + moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L'));

    var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
    console.log("changing locale to: " + locale);
    moment.locale(locale);

    console.log("updated locale: " + moment.locale());
    console.log("updated date format = " + moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L'));

    $('input.txt-date').on('change', function() {
        var v = $(this).val();
        if (!v) return; // No value in the textbox

        v = moment(v); // Parse the date
        if (!v.isValid) {
            alert("Invalid Date!");
            return;
        }

        // Re-format the date
        $(this).val(v.format("D MMM YYYY"));
    });
});
```

Here's the output in the browser's log:

> initial locale = en
>
> initial date format = MM/DD/YYYY
>
> changing locale to: en-GB
>
> updated locale: en
>
> updated date format = MM/DD/YYYY

Essentially, moment.js seems to assume that I should be using English (US) regional settings, rather than English (UK). Changing the locale (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725882/locale-detection-with-moment-js)) based on the user language seems to have made no difference.

All I want to do is to be able to parse date strings in either the user's local/regional format (or D MMM YYYY if they enter it that way). Can anyone provide any pointers?

---

**Solution**

Thanks to Phani for the help. In order to get this working you'll need to include the **moment-with-locales.js** file (which can be found at "https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js" but is also included in the NuGet package).

The updated JavaScript is as follows:

```
$(function () {

    // Configure moment to use the user's locale
    moment.locale(window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language);

    $('input.txt-date').on('change', function () {
        var v = $(this).val();
        if (!v) return; // No value in the textbox

        // Parse the date specified
        var fmt = moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L');
        v = moment(v, [fmt, "D MMM YY", "D MMM YYYY"]);

        // If the date is invalid, warn the user
        if (!v.isValid()) {
            alert("Invalid Date!");
            return;
        }

        // Re-format the date
        $(this).val(v.format("D MMM YYYY"));
    });
});
```

This combination has worked with every valid date I've could throw at it.

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the question; instead, add an answer below.

Comment: It's a common enough way of rewarding the person who got me 90% the way there by flagging their response as an answer, whist displaying the final solution to my issue in such a manner that it won't be overlooked as a response that's not flagged as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because of the `moment locales` missing or not imported. Once you import the locales, you can change the locale. You can find the moment locales imported from CDN (below).

Note that I have hardcoded the locale to `en-gb` as per your needs.

```js
$(function () {          
 console.log(moment.locales())
 console.log("initial locale: " + moment.locale());
 console.log("initial date format:= " + moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L'));

 var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
 console.log("changing locale to: " + locale);
 moment.locale("en-gb");

 console.log("updated locale: " + moment.locale());
 console.log("updated date format = " + moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L'));

 $('input.txt-date').on('change', function () {
  var v = $(this).val();
  if (!v) return; // No value in the textbox

  v = moment(v); // Parse the date
  if (!v.isValid) {
   alert("Invalid Date!");
   return;
  }

  // Re-format the date
  $(this).val(v.format("D MMM YYYY"));
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<!-- load all available momentjs locales -->
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="txt-date" name="foo" />
```

Comment: The addition of the locales file seems to fix the issue of the reported date format, which is now coming back correctly as DD/MM/YYYY. Unfortunately the parsing is still using US formatting - entering 01/09/2018 results in 09 Jan 2018, even though  moment.locale() is reporting "en-gb"

Comment: Got it! I needed to add the formats to the moment(v) method. I'll put the solution in the question - thanks for your help!