# How does Moment JS reads locale/language

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to show date in localized format, so I used

`moment().format('l');`

function of Moment JS https://momentjs.com/#multiple-locale-support

It is not working as expected in different systems/browsers

root cause of the issue is that Moment reads current locale as "en" even when the environment is France ("fr")

```
console.log('moment lang: '+moment.lang());
console.log('userLanguage: '+window.navigator.userLanguage);
console.log('language: '+window.navigator.language);
```

Results produced:

```
moment lang: en
userLanguage: fr-FR
language: fr-FR
```

Moment will give correct locale formatted date if I explicitly set

`moment().locale(window.navigator.userLanguage||window.navigator.language);`

Do I really need to explicitly set locale in Moment or I am doing something wrong?

A note for duplicate question issue: question is how does Momentjs reads locale.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Locale detection with Moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725882/locale-detection-with-moment-js)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have set desired locale using [`moment.locale`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/):

> By default, Moment.js comes with English (United States) locale strings. If you need other locales, you can load them into Moment.js for later use.
>
> To load a locale, pass the key and the string values to `moment.locale`.
>
> Once you load a locale, it becomes the active locale. To change active locales, simply call `moment.locale` with the key of a loaded locale.

Please note tha lang is deprecated in 2.8.1

> ```
> // Deprecated in 2.8.1
> moment.lang(String);
> ```