# How to format date in moment.js based on current locale?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I want to format the date based on the current browser locale. Like `navigator.language`. This works

```
moment(new Date()).locale(navigator.language).format("llll");
```

but do I need to use the `.locale(navigator.language)`? I want to know if I need that explicitly, or does moment use the current locale by default, so that I would just need

```
moment(new Date()).format("llll");
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Locale detection with Moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725882/locale-detection-with-moment-js)

Comment: The linked answer is 4 years old. But I [checked the docs](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/06-i18n/01-changing-locale/) and it seems to be still true.

Comment: [The docs referred to in the other question](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/)

Comment: but that answer doesn't answer my question. That only says how to change it. I want to know if it uses browser locale by default.

Comment: and yes im using the moment with locale.js file

Comment: You might just use `new Date().toLocaleString(undefined)`, which will use the current browser language for the locale.