# Make a Multi Language system in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I search a method to make my Multi Language system with MySQL or File.
I need to make it in JavaScript, I thought with an object and langue name:

```
var lang = 
{
    fr:
    {
        welcome     : 'bonjour',
        good_bye    : 'à bientôt'
    },
    en:
    {
        welcome     : 'welcome',
        good_bye    : 'good bye'
    },
    es:
    {
        welcome     : 'holà',
        good_bye    : 'adios'
    }
}
```

Do you have an better idea?

Comment: Nope, that's probably the way I would do it.

Comment: My last question, How I can make a system with arguments?
welcome: 'Welcome %s', with printf like PHP?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference

Comment: I'm not sure that you understood me.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at http://i18next.com/ - quite a handy library, built in string replacement etc.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to interrogate that JS object would be to write a simple function using the country and word as arguments:

```
function translate(country, word) {
   return lang[country][word]
}
```

And then use it like this, perhaps:

```
var name = 'Jonas';
var country = 'es';
translate(country, 'welcome') + ' ' + name; // "holà Jonas"
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cw7rL8qp/1/)

UPDATE:

```
function doWelcome(country, name) {
   return lang[country].welcome + ', ' + name + '. Good game.';
}
```

And then use it like this, perhaps:

```
doWelcome('es', 'Jonas'); // "holà, Jonas. Good game"
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cw7rL8qp/3/)

Comment: Yeah. I know that, now I'm trying to make a system with args.

Comment: I don't know what a "system with args" is, sorry.

Comment: translate(country, 'welcome') + ' ' + name; // "holà Jonas" WORKS but, if it's "Welcome Jonas, good game", with your system I need to make 2 str: "Welcome", and "good game". Or I can to do: "Welcome %s, good game!".

Comment: I found https://gist.github.com/tbranyen/1049426, I'll try to understand it correctly but works perfectly.

Comment: Yes but I know this method, I'm asking if... I have my result: https://gist.github.com/tbranyen/1049426

Comment: I think the best if just {p} like a "Params" or other "text" to inform it's a param. I don't think I need {1}, {2}, because rarely use many time the same arg. Just "{a} help {a}".format('Andy', 'Jonas'), no?

Comment: Your code return "Welcome Jonas, how are you? (It's Shaiming who talk to {0})"

Comment: That's not the way I would do it, no. and my code returns "Welcome Jonas, how are you? (It's Shaiming who talk to Jonas)"

Comment: Yes but I don't need to use {1}, {2}, etc. just argument: 'text number: {a} | other: {a} for example

Comment: But {a} is a example, I can use something else.

Comment: @JonasGame: Andy appears to have made a great effort on your behalf, even if was not what you wanted. Would you consider upvoting his answer, to thank him for his time?

Comment: @helfer: Sorry I'm new here and I forgotten, i'm going right now    -    "votes up require 15 reputation"