# Use document.getElementById to retrieve a value

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I am tring to retrieve the language value of my page, FR for French or ENG for English.

I am using `document.getElementById("contentzone").innerHTML;` to retrieve my data
**Unfortunatly the html element lang is always=en, that's why I have to find an other way...**

that returns

```
<span style="display: none;">IE BUMPER</span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.tools.min.jsdbx?FRv=03-10-2015_0442"></script>
```

How I can retrieve the src url? *(/jquery.tools.min.jsbx?FRv=03-10-2015_0442)*
I have to retrieve "FR" which is the current language of my user, after I can parse the data and just get FR.

I've an other element on my page which displays the current language.

The html page structure is:

```
<html class="ltr chrome" lang="en">
<head> </head>
<body>
    <div class="my_site_layout">
    <div id="topzone">
        <div id ="conn-infos">
            <form class="conn-infos">
            <div class="login">
                FR
```

How I can access to this data (the string equal to FR) in Javascript? Because I think my first method with `document.getElementByID` to retrieve the name script is dirty.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of the previous answers, I recommend

```
document.documentElement.getAttribute('lang');
```

`document.documentElement` refers to the `<html>` element of the page. `.getAttribute()` is used to retrieve an HTML attribute. If the attribute *were* to be *actual text* in an element. Your question which I felt wasn't to clear mentioned that there was an element that displayed the language :

```
document.getElementById('element').innerHTML.trim().toUpperCase()
```

Possible this could work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('login')[0].innerHTML.trim().split(' ')[0].toUpperCase();
```

---

[getAttribute() Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

[HTML Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors)

Comment: Unfortunatly the html element lang is always=en, that's why I have to find an other way...

Comment: @Xifeat Updated again

Comment: Thank you vihan1086, this is amazing I understand better how it works, and trim() is really usefull

Comment: @Xifeat No problem :)   I recommend looking up "JavaScript string manipulation" to learn more on string manipulation to retrieve the data you want in the future

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm gonna find some exercices about that !

Answer (score 1):

There might be better ways to do this, but the quickest approach that comes to mind is to use getElementsByTagName.

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("lang");
```