# send cookie inside request angularjs http get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have the following http get , that I would like to send  a cookie with a language on the request, but turns out with $cookieStore, it sends the cookie outside of the request

```
$cookieStore.put("language", "pt-PT");
```

I tried this as well

```
var myObject = {
    headers: { 'language': 'pt-PT'}
}//ignored

return $http.get(comm.endpoints.getEntityFinancialPosition, myObject );
```

In my debug I can see that this just created a new header that is not sent inside the cookie [image]

Comment: Can you please add the desired behaviour? Right now it's a bit unclear what your question is.

Comment: Inside the cookie, where it says language = us-US , I want it to say pt-PT since that is what I have on my code

Comment: Great :) Edit your question and add that that's the result you're looking for. Not everyone looks through the comments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216155/can-i-change-accept-language-request-header-with-angularjs/37439756

Comment: @JameeIM thanks but I am not asking about the accept language , but the cookie itself carrying a variable called language and then it's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of the cookie is restricted with the domain option. If page domain is different than API domain cookie will not be sent when making a request. To fix that set the right domain for the cookie `$cookieStore.put("language", "pt-PT", {domain: 'requestdomain.com'})`.

Comment: This helped the cookie to disappear from outside the cookie field, it no longer appears as a header tho this doesn't seem to change the language for me and I don't think the domain is wrong, thanks , I will keep looking