# AngularJS how to use browser language detection?

Tags: angularjs

Hi I get text from database with http.get .How to get with browser detection ? How to use if clause ? I don't want to use translate.toogle()

```
    var mainCtrl = function ($scope, $http, $sce, $location,$timeout,$routeParams, toastr) {

    $scope.showPage = false;     
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.showPage = true;
            },2000);


        $scope.trustedHtml = function (plainText) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(plainText);
        }

        $http.get('admin/api/?s=getAbout').success(

         ##### if browser En_en
            function(r){
                $scope.about = r.text_en;

         ##### if browser De_de
            function(r){
                $scope.about = r.text_de;
            }
        );

};
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can get the browser language using `navigator.language`:

```
var lang = $window.navigator.language || $window.navigator.userLanguage; 
if (lang === 'en-US') {
  console.log("language is english");
}
```

Comment: $window.navigator.language is only the browser's UI language and not the accepted languages.

Comment: It doesn't work with Chrome. The solution from Anushree is better.

Comment: I'd use if(lang.indexOf('en') != -1) because there are: en-Au, en-SG, en-GB ...etc.

Answer (score 13):

```
navigator.languages
    ? navigator.languages[0]
    : (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage)
```

is the best way.

ref:  [JavaScript for detecting browser language preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)