# How do I set the default voice for SpeechSynthesisUtterance in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, text-to-speech, webspeech-api

I have a Javascript app that uses `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` for text to speech. On some browsers it uses the wrong voice (language). For example, on one browser whose language is set to English, the TTS ends up using a German voice.

Is there a configuration option to set the voice used?

Comment: Sounds like this bug reported for Chrome OS https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=453584

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [speech API spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html) says that browsers can decide which voice to use by default, and that each *utterance language* may have a different default voice.

#### [voice `default` attribute](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#dfn-voicedefault):

> This attribute is true for at most one voice per language. There may be a different default for each language. It is user agent
>   dependent how default voices are determined.

The default utterence language is decided by the HTML `lang` attribute:

#### [utterance `lang` attribute](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#dfn-utterancelang):

> This attribute specifies the language of the speech
>   synthesis for the utterance, using a valid BCP 47 language tag.
>   [[BCP47](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/)] If unset it remains unset for getting in script, but will
>   default to use the lang of the html document root element and
>   associated hierachy. This default value is computed and used when the
>   input request opens a connection to the recognition service.

This implies that, to use a British voice by default:

```
<html lang="en-GB">

<body>
  <script>
  var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Toodle pip');
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this did not change the default voice for me in Chrome 46 (my default language is `en-GB`; I also get a German voice by default).

You *could* use `navigator.language` as the default utterance language, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3335420/2806996) it is not a reliable indicator of browser settings (for me it evaluates to `en-US`, which is in my list of languages but is not my default).

Comment: Yes - I saw how to do this programmatically. But I don't want to hardcode the language to 'en-US'. Is there a way to set it to the default language of the browser? Is there no config setting for this?

Comment: I just re-read the spec. It seems that the default utterance lang is picked up from the HTML  `lang` attribute. Can you try setting `lang` on your root `<html>`?

Comment: I just tried it (and updated the answer) - no luck. I still get German by default. I could be mis-reading the spec, or perhaps Chrome's default language detection ignores it.

Comment: I haven't got an answer, but this is useful information. So, I am accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome seems to ignore the HTML lang property. The solution is to set the property of the utterance:

```
<script>
    var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Toodle pip');
    utterance.lang='en-US'; // for US english, en-GR for british
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
</script>
```

Comment: No audible difference between en-US och en-GR running that code.

Comment: It should probably be en-GB