# Browser language detection

Tags: angular, typescript, translate, language-detection

I need in my Angular2 app detect browser language. Based on this language I need to send request (to a REST API of backend) with localization and IDs of my variables, which I need to translate. After that I received response with translated variables.

So the app workflow is to detect browser language, ok it is for example `en-US`, after that I am going to sent request to backend give me lang for en-US for variables with IDs 1,2,3,4,5. The response is `{{id:1, var:pay}, {id:1, var:title}}` etc.

So how can I detect with Angular2 (developed with typescript) browser language?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference

Comment: Not sure this is a duplicate - Angular 2/4 has a special injectable to help with localization, LOCALE_ID:  https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
```

**2021 Edit**

Looks like `userLanguage` does not exist anymore (at least with Typescript lib).

And it's not on docs : just use  `navigator.language`

[MDN DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language)

Comment: @Loutocký FYI, `navigator.language` is the standard, according to [specs](http://w3c.github.io/html/webappapis.html#language-preferences). `userLanguage` is a non-standard implementation in some browsers, and the only one in [IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language#Browser_compatibility) (besides `browserLanguage`).

Comment: Thank you for your time and informations.

Comment: Property 'userLanguage' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.

Comment: const lang = navigator.language || window.navigator.language;
Worked for me