# Language variables in i18next

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next

I'm using `i18next` for the internationalization of an application.

I am initializing it like this:

```
i18n.init({debug: false, getAsync: false, resGetPath: _this.buildPath + _this.i18nPath + '__lng__/__ns__.json'});
```

What do the variables `__lng__` and `__ns__` stand for?

Answer (score 0):

- `__lng__` is the language to load
- `__ns__` is the namespace to load

Basically it means that if you initialise with `lng: 'en-US'` it will try to load:

1. `_this.buildPath + _this.i18nPath + 'en-US/translation.json'`
2. `_this.buildPath + _this.i18nPath + 'en/translation.json'`
3. `_this.buildPath + _this.i18nPath + 'dev/translation.json'`

Because dev is the default falback language & translation is the default namespace.

You may find the docs [here](https://i18next.github.io/i18next/pages/doc_init.html) useful as it shows some more ways of using them depending on how your backend works.

EDIT: There are a number of ways to set the language which is loaded. The simplest way to do this is by passing the value as the `lng` parameter of `i18n.init()`. An example of this would be:

```
i18n.init({
    debug: false, 
    getAsync: false, 
    lng: _this.language,
    fallbackLng: _this.defaultLanguage,
    resGetPath: _this.buildPath + _this.i18nPath + '__lng__/__ns__.json'
});
```

This example is the same as yours but explicitly sets the language. I also set `fallbackLng` but this is mainly useful if you accept the language from a user in some way (e.g from [browser language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)) so that any unsupported languages will fallback to a default. If you only allow selection from pre-approved values then this may not be required.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! Generally I understand now, how it works.

But the variable `lng` is never initialized, where does it get it's value from in that case?

Comment: I added some bits to the answer which hopefully make it more clear how you can set the language but I realise now that may not be what you meant. If you meant how is the language being set for you now then it comes from [this function](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/1.11.2/i18next.js#L1843) in i18next which detects the correct language to use from cookies, localStorage & then `window.navigator` properties.

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for :) thank you very much one more time, you really helped me a lot!