# Locale selected by browser from my extensions available locales

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

My extension has two locales in the `_locales` folder, it has `ja` and `ru`.

The manifest.json has `"default_locale": "ru"`.

But now let's say for example a Spanish user installs my extension, their `chrome.i18n.getUILanguage()` and `chrome.i18n.getAcceptLanguages()` results in `['es', 'es-ES']`.

Is there a way I can determine what locale the browser is displaying my extension material in?

### EDIT - What i currently do:

I XHR the _locales directory (make sure to have the ending `/` otherwise XHR fails) I then get all the directories. Then i find a common key among all files that has a unique value across all files. Then I do `chrome.i18n.getMessage(key)` and see which directories message.json gave that. It works but I just thought there would be a built in way.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference) if it can help you.

Comment: Thanks @KENdi I edited the question to show the current way I do it. That SO question doesnt help too much.

Comment: Add `chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@ui_locale")` to the list of things that don't work..