# Datatables/MomentJS - Change date format when locale changes

Tags: angularjs, datatables, momentjs

I'm trying to display a properly formatted date in a Datatable column. I'm using [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) to detect and format the cell properly, as it comes as a `yyyyMMdd` (i.e. `20051201`) string from the database:

```
columns: [
    {
        data: "fechaPago", 
        "render": function(data){
            return (moment(data).isValid()) ? moment(data).format("DD/MM/YYYY") : "-";
        }
    },
]
```

Which works exactly as expected:

[image]

Now, I'm struggling to implement a more flexible approach, and let the current locale determine the format. We have 3 available languages in our webapp, and **I want the Datatable to detect the current language and change the format** (from `dd/MM/yyyy` to `MM/dd/yyyy`, if it's in English).

I have tried to use `'LLLL'` as the format, but it returns the whole date with letters, and I can't figure out how to modify it.

Comment: Does [`format('L')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) satisfy your needs?

Comment: @VincenzoC Thanks for the help Vincenzo. It partially does, as it simplifies the formatting a lot. However, it's not changing the format when I change the language.

Comment: Do you already have locale info in your code or you are asking how to get browser locale (in this case search on SO, e.g. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1043339/4131048))?

Comment: @VincenzoC I guess I could import $locale into the directive to get the current language, but I can't figure how to take into account the conditional in the render (if -> locale = "pt-pt" -> then -> show me the date in "dd/MM/yyyy" format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use moment [`locale(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/) function to set locale for a moment oblect or [`moment.locale(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) to set moment locale globally.

To get localized day, month and year use `L` token in the [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Your code will be like the following:

```
columns: [
  {
    data: "fechaPago",
    "render": function(data){
      var locale = // get current locale code
      return (moment(data).isValid()) ? moment(data).locale(locale).format("L") : "-";
    }
  },
]
```

Remember to use `moment-with-locales.js` (or import required locales).

Comment: Hi again Vincenzo. I tried using your solution, and even though yyyyMMdd string gets formatted to MM-dd-yyyy, it does not change when I switch the global locale, not even when I reload.

Comment: @wickedchild the problem could be the way you get locale, try to test my solution hardcoding locale (`var locale = 'en-gb';`) and rember to use [`moment-with-locales.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js) (or import required locales).

Comment: That's it! I was using the regular moment.js, switching to the other one did the trick :) Thanks a lot for your time, Vincenzo :)

Comment: You're welcome! I've edited my answer adding the info of my last comment.