# How can I get language of the android device in Ionic3, Cordova and Angular4 application?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to get the android device language from the app developed using Ionic3, Cordova and Angular4.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [cordova-plugin-globalization](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-globalization/) which also offers an [ionic-native wrapper](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/globalization/). It offers a lot of useful methods, but you are probably looking for `getPreferredLanguage()` or `getLocaleName()`.

**Installation:**

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-globalization
npm install --save @ionic-native/globalization
```

**Example:**

```
import { Globalization } from '@ionic-native/globalization';
constructor(private globalization: Globalization) { 
  this.globalization.getPreferredLanguage()
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

Comment: Globalization is deprecated https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization#deprecation-notice

Answer (score 15):

`window.navigator.language` worked for me with no plugin. I didn't check to see how the results compare to the Globalization plugin, but I got results like: Android: "en-us", "es-us" and on iOS: "en-US" and "es-XL"

also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4079798/431296 -`window.navigator.userLanguage` wasn't defined on either Android or iOS, so I didn't include it

Comment: For those of you who are wondering, "window.navigator.language" is part of the ECMA Internationalization API which is what the Ionic team recommends using instead of the Globalization Plugin.  See Filip Floryan's answer to this question for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53831546/3513260

Answer (score 6):

Follow up to David's answer, the Globalization API is deprecated.

> With the [ECMA Internationalization API](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/) now supported on iOS, Android and Windows devices, this plugin is not required any more.
>    * Migrating from this plugin to the [ECMA Internationalization API](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/) is explained in this [Cordova blog post](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/11/20/migrate-from-cordova-globalization-plugin.html).

Comment: To save some people a little bit of digging: the blog post mentioned in this reply recommends using "window.navigator.language" (although they use it without the leading "window").  This is what Stan Kurdziel was referring to in his answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50457743/3513260

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ngx-translate,

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
  console.log(this.translate.getBrowserLang());
}
```

works fine on the devices and in the browser. It's returning "en" or "de".

Answer (score 1):

For ionic 5 with capacitor:

```
npm install @capacitor/device
npx cap sync
```

in code:

```
import { Device } from '@capacitor/device';
console.log((await Device.getLanguageCode()).value); // en-US
```

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/device

Answer (score 0):

**Ionic 4**

In Ionic we call it [Globalization](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/globalization) performs operations specific to the user's locale, language, and timezone.

> **Installation** : Terminal

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-globalization
npm install @ionic-native/globalization
```

> ***Usages***: Any Component or service file.

```
import { Globalization } from '@ionic-native/globalization/ngx';
constructor(private global: Globalization) { }
...


this.global.getPreferredLanguage()
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```