# shiny application: get browser language settings

Tags: r, shiny, internationalization

My question is rather simple. I am building a Shiny application where the user can switch between predefined languages with a button. 
However I would like to start each session with the user's language already displayed in the text, so is there a way to **retrieve the language** defined in the browser or operating system of the user, like as a function that returns a character variable?

I saw that there were many questions about this subject already on this site, but there are for other computing languages than R/Shiny and I have no idea how to adapt them to R. Thanks

Comment: For the multilingual part of my app I'm using parts of the code of Chrisphe Ladroue here https://github.com/chrislad/multilingualShinyApp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is based on the content from an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference) and a [blog link](https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/). Code flow:

A plain javascript code to get Browser language is run using `runjs` of `shinyjs` package (instead this could be run with `tags$script` too). Also note that the browser language value is stored in a javascript variable `language` which is then passed back to R and displayed as a text.

```
jscode <- "var language =  window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
Shiny.onInputChange('mydata', language);
console.log(language);"
library(shiny); library(shinyjs)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),

    "This is your browser language",
    textOutput('your_lang')

  ),
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    runjs(jscode)
 output$your_lang <- renderPrint(input$mydata)
  }
)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, it works well. Can you explain how this piece of javascript works? It generates a new input variable?

Comment: @agenis I've added some description please check and also please mark right if it works. Thanks.