# Detect user language who visit my website (React, i18next)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, i18next

I am developing a multilanguage application using React, `i18next` and `i18next-browser-languagedetector`.

`i18next-browser-languagedetector` detect user language in the browser with support for: cookie, localStorage, navigator, querystring, htmlTag

Should I verify Accept-Language from HTTP request header with another module ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript for detecting browser language preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

request headers get evaluated on the server side so not part of browser language detection -> the serverside middleware for eg. express comes with its own detector:

https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware#language-detection

also the serverside rendering examples for react-i18next use that: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/example/nextjs/server.js#L16

Comment: Thank you for this details =)

Comment: second link is invalid now