# Made a redirection depending on the language of the visitor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm building a blog with Gatsby with support for 2 languages.

Most of the concerns about the internationalization of the web are done, but I don't how I could redirect to the visitors based on their language. For example, if a Spanish person visits the index of my pages, I would like to redirect them to `/es/index` route.

Comment: I hope this Blog can help you `https://www.techrepublic.com/article/detect-foreign-language-support-using-javascript/`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript for detecting browser language preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)

Answer (score 0):

You can use vanilla javascript to get the user language from the browser

```
window.navigator.language
```

then redirect based on the language gotten.