# How to show a UTC time as local time in a webpage?

Tags: asp.net, datetime, utc

I have a database that holds a time as UTC. This time can be shown in a webpage, so I’ve been asked to show it as local time in the page as it can be viewed from any country. A colleague mentioned something about getting the country settings from the current thread (on the server) but I couldn’t find any details on this. Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/how-do-i-display-a-date-time-in-the-users-locale-format-and-time-offset

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you (and your website) are comfortable with javascript, there is a very easy way to accomplish this.

First, on the server side, you would have the UTC date/time formatted in RFC 3339 format (the standard for internet time used by, among other protocols, icalendar). The basic syntax of RFC 3339 is:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
```

Such that where I am, the time would be:

```
2010-05-04T05:52:33
```

But when the time is not local, but UTC, you add a `Z` to the end to denote this. So in my case, since I'm at -0500 hours from GMT, the same time above would be:

```
2010-05-04T10:52:33Z
```

So, first you get the server to output the above to your web page's javascript. The javascript can then parse that timestamp and it will output the date and time adjusted to the browser's time zone (which is determined by the computer hosting the browser). You should remember that if a user is from Tokyo and is viewing your website in Spain, they will see the timestamp in Tokyo time unless they've adjusted their computer's clock.

So the javascript would be:

```
    var time_string_utc = some_server_variable; // timestamp from server
    var time_string_utc_epoch = Date.parse(time_string_utc);
    var time_utc = new Date();
    time_utc.setTime(time_string_utc_epoch);
```

At this point, you have a javascript date object set to your UTC timestamp. A quick explanation of what happens above:

The first variable assumes you have passed the timestamp string to that variable from the server.

The second variable uses the `Date.parse()` method to convert the string to an epoch timestamp.

The third variable creates the unset Date object.

The last line line uses `setTime` method, which sets a Date object from an epoch timestamp.

Now that you have the object, you can output it to the user as you see fit. As a simple experiment, you can use:

```
document.write(time_utc);
```

which, if you are in my timezone using the UTC timestamp I started off with:

```
2010-05-04T10:52:33Z
```

would give:

```
 Tue May 04 2010 05:52:33 GMT-0500 (CST)
```

but you can use various javascript methods to format the time into something much more pleasant looking.

No need to guess the user's country or even adjust your timestamp, so long as you trust the user's local browser/computer time zone.

Again, the short version:

```
    var time_string_utc = some_server_variable; // UTC time from server
    var time_string_utc_epoch = Date.parse(some_server_variable);
    var time_utc = new Date();
    time_utc.setTime(time_string_utc_epoch);
    document.write(time_utc);
```

Comment: Your code looks like it will do what I need. The problem I have is that I don't know much about javascript. At the moment I am populating my DataGrid with the datetime like this: <asp:Label ID="lblLastActive" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LastActiveTime")%>'></asp:Label> How could I use your script with this ?

Comment: If you use set classes or IDs for your elements containing time, you could have the javascript adjust the times on page load. I don't know enough about ASP to know how your code will become HTML, but if you can give me a sample of the HTML of the time stamps, I could show you how to add javascript to adjust it after page load.

Comment: @Anthony In your two code snippets, the `time_string_utc` variable is not used. Would be clearer to use it or remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-do-and-donts) which dives deeper in the dos and donts of handling daylight saving problem across timezones

Answer (score 0):

Of-course is possible. You just need to find that `country settings` to detect the country your user comes from, and then modify the displayed date to fit that country's time.You can also find another way to detect the user country.(maybe from his ip address).

I am sure that the best way to manage this is let your colleague know that you need more details about the country settings implementation on your project and how can you use it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Thinking about it I don't think it is possible to display the local time once you have the client’s culture. I'd certainly be interested to see your colleagues suggestion.

Getting the US culture, for example, won't help as the US has many timezones.

I think using Javascript like Anthony suggests would be the way to go...

OLD:

You can override the [InitializeCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(VS.80).aspx)() method with code that sets the current (chosen or browser reporting) cultures:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new 
            CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
```

Comment: So ASP.NET can detect the visitor's time zone automatically? How?

Comment: I don't think it can get the time zone automatically. If you get the culture from the browser, or user - "getting the country settings" - then that's part of the way. I guess that's what his collegue meant.

Comment: Having said that, getting the US culture, for example, won't help as the US has many timezones. Maybe my answer does stink for ASP.NET too. This is an interesting one...

Answer (score -1):

this is how I've done it in PHP in the login file which connects to MySQL database:

```
//set local timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver'); //use local TZ
```

Then, every time you access the DB, you are setting the timezone for that session and any input/output associated with it.